# Expected primary expression before enum array error?

Tags: c++, enums

I know it's really simple code but I'm new and I couldn't find answers that explained this exactly.

```
#include<iostream>  
using namespace std;  

int main(){

//This is where codeblocks notes the error.
enum board{'b','o','a','r','d'};  

return 0;  
}
```

Comment: This is simply a syntax error.  If you explain what you are trying to achieve someone will be able to show how

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum

Comment: I just found that it works better without quotation marks around the characters inside the brackets. :p

Answer (score 3):

I think you meant

```
enum board{b, o, a, r, d};
```

You can't use `char` literals as your `enum` names, but you can assign your `enum` names to `char` literals, like...

```
enum board{b='b', o='o', a='a', r='r', d='d'};
```